# UIImage for button changes incorrectly when pressed first time

Tags: swift, uibutton, uiimage

I want to change button's image when pressed. The code is below. The problem is in the fact that when you press button first time, that part of the code after "else" statement is being executed and visually nothing changes. Then everything works ok with the second and following clicks.

```
@IBOutlet weak var beenHereButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func beenHereButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject)
{
    if beenHereButton.imageView!.image == UIImage(named: "locationButton")
    {

        beenHereButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "locationButtonPressed"), forState: .Normal)
        print("Button Pressed")

    }
    else
    {

        beenHereButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "locationButton"), forState: .Normal)
        print("Button released")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not compare images in this way; looks like you initialized image from storyboard, and its not exactly the same as initializing by `UIImage` class. Use other solution. Probably you any way will need indicator in other parts of code, so make flag property:

```
var buttonPressed = false
@IBOutlet weak var beenHereButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func beenHereButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject)
{
    if !buttonPressed 
    {
        beenHereButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "locationButtonPressed"), forState: .Normal)
        print("Button Pressed")
        buttonPressed = true
    }
    else
    {
        beenHereButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "locationButton"), forState: .Normal)
        print("Button released")
        buttonPressed = false
    }
}
```

Comment: I've just tried now and it works perfectly! Really appreciate this!